# Scala type parameterization, Shapeless - could not find implicit value for parameter Generic

Tags: scala, shapeless

I'm unable to implement shapeless.Generic with scala type parameterized functions. In the following piece of code, I am getting error "could not find implicit value for parameter gen: shapeless.Generic[T]".

```
  def foo[T](instance: T) = {
    val gen = shapeless.Generic[T]  //getting error in this line!!!
    val values = gen.to(instance)
    println(values)
  }
  case class Bar(x:String, y:String)
  var bar = Bar("a","b")
  foo(bar)
```

Is there anything I am missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  def foo[T, HL <: HList](instance: T)(
    implicit gen: Generic.Aux[T, HL]
  ) = {
    val values = gen to instance
    println(values)
  }

case class Bar(x: String, y: String)
```

You need to use the `Aux` pattern usually, generics are macro materialised but produce an arbitrary type that's exposed as an abstract type member. If you don't understand all the words here just yet, read more [**here**](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/shapeless/generic.scala#L148).

Comment: Thank you, I never thought it was this simple. Also, thank you for letting me know about Aux pattern and I will go through your provided link as well. :)

Comment: @RaKa Happy to help, Miles is an amazing man as you'll discover, and so are plenty of other folks behind shapeless.